# Choice of axes in resonantly driven two level system

Tags: optics, quantum-optics, two-level-system, bloch-oscillation

Consider a two-level atom with a transition at angular frequency $\omega_0$ and $\mu_{12}=2 \times 10^{-29} \text{Cm}$ subjected to a sequence of two resonant pulses. The first pulse has electric field given by $\mathcal{E}(t)=\mathcal{E}_1 \cos \left(\omega_0 t \right)$ and duration $ \tau_1$ while the second has $\mathcal{E}(t) = \mathcal{E}_2 \cos \left(\omega_0 t + \phi \right)$ and duration $\tau_2$. $\mathcal{E}_1$ and $\mathcal{E}_2$ are both constant during the pulses, and the pulse length is much shorter than the dephasing time $ T_2$. Given that the system starts in the ground state, find the final state when:

| Case | E1 (V/m) | t1 (ns) | E2 (V/m) | t2 (ns) | phi (deg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 4139 | 1 | 6209 | 2 | 0 |
| b | 827.8 | 10 | 3311 | 5 | 90 |
| c | 27,590 | 0.3 | 5,5190 | 0.3 | 45 |

While solving the question I have selected $x$ axis as my rotation while $z$ axis for changing the phase. **I want to understand why this is only the particular choice of the axis why not any other combination.**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to understand why only the particular choice of the axis of rotation and axis of phase is applicable why can't I use any other axis.